Fortran runtime error: Bad value value during integer read
Error is:
At line 124 of file calib3.f (unit = 17, file = './temp.clean')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read

Error termination. Backtrace:

Could not print backtrace: libbacktrace could not find executable to open
#0  0x6f8aecb4
#1  0x6f8a11ce
#2  0x6f81fac4
#3  0x6f8ad971
#4  0x6f8c404f
#5  0x6f89b375
#6  0x4030cf
#7  0x405a50
#8  0x401287

Code is:
     open(unit=obslun,status='old',file=obsf,access='sequential')
 do 1001 i=1,8
     extraf(i) = 0
     extraa(i) = 0
     extrat(i) = ' '
1001  continue
      read(unit=obslun,fmt=60,end=2000) regno,
     1      (amnt(i),time(i),i=1,21),
     2      (extraf(i),extraa(i),extrat(i),i=1,2)
      read(unit=obslun,fmt=61,end=2000)
     1      (amnt(i),time(i),i=22,41),    
     2      (extraf(i),extraa(i),extrat(i),i=3,4),
   etc
Format 60 is:
60    format(1x,a4,1x,21(i1,a1),2(i4,i1,a1))
The data is:
 G001 3M3M3M3M N3W N3W2D2D N N N N N N N2W N N N10011W10021W            
      1W2W1W1W2W N1W N2W2D N N5W N N N5W N N N            2131   1 0 0 0 0
      2M2M N2M4M N1M2M2M2M2M3M1M1M1M3M3M N2M3M N N N N1W2W N N N N            
      1222224422222222
      1W1W1W1W1W1W1W1W1W1W1W1W2W3W N1W1W1W1W1W3M1M1M1W1M N2W N            
      114212W N N2W3W N N1W1W2M2W1W3M4M3M1W1W2M2M1W N N N N            
       16  0 14  0   0  02 0 00 902W2W2W2W2W2D7W1W1M3W3W N N2W N R N1W1W1W

I have tried commenting out the next 6 lines of input. I have tried the following format statements:
60    format(1x,a5,21(i1,a1),2(i4,i1,a1)) 
60    format(1x,a4,2x,21(i1,a1),2(i4,i1,a1))

I have tried some print statements
print *,'Line 0'
     read(unit=obslun,fmt=60,end=2000) regno,
 1      (amnt(i),time(i),i=1,21),
 2      (extraf(i),extraa(i),extrat(i),i=1,2)
     print *, regno, (amnt(i),time(i),i=1,21),(extraf(i),extraa(i),extrat(i),i=1,2)
     print *, 'Line 2'
     read(unit=obslun,fmt=61,end=2000)
 1      (amnt(i),time(i),i=22,41),    
 2      (extraf(i),extraa(i),extrat(i),i=3,4),
 3      mlktea,mlkcof,mlksub,makdrk,
 4      mlktyp,sugtea,sugcof,sugsub,sugcoc
     print *,(amnt(i),time(i),i=22,41),(extraf(i),extraa(i),extrat(i),i=3,4)
     print *,'Line 3'  etc
and got 
 G001            3 M           3 M           3 M           3 M           0 N           3 W           0    
N           3 W           2 D           2 D           0 N           0 N           0 N           0 N            

0 N           0 N           0 N           2 W           0 N           0 N           0 N
1 W           2 W           1 W           1 W           2 W           0 N           1 W
0 N           2 W           2 D           0 N           0 N           5 W           0 N           0 N
0 N           5 W           0 N           0 N           0 N           0
At line 124 of file calib3.f (unit = 17, file = './temp.clean')
Fortran runtime error: Bad value during integer read
I hoped that the data would be read in and it wasn't. I have indented every line by 4 as I have code     
that is not properly formatted and I cannot post this question.

Thanks for your help in advance.
Trisha

